# How test if connection is down in txmongo

Tags: mongodb, twisted, pymongo

How to test if query is successful, for example due to connection problems? I am using [txmongo](https://github.com/fiorix/mongo-async-python-driver) driver with twisted.

My application takes something from RabbitMQ and put it into MongoDB.I need to be able to test if there are some issues, so that I won't acknowledge the message and it will be stored in queue.

I looked at the code but couldn't find a proper way. I am newb in using twisted.
There is a warning `RuntimeWarning("not connected")` but it's not an exception to be caught. Maybe it's possible to test `factory.size > 0`